# Ошибка: Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found

Tags: php, xml, captcha, яндекс-smart-captcha

При считывании xml файла с сервера яндекс Smart Captcha возникает подобная ошибка, в чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Если говорить точнее проблема в этой строчке:

```
$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement($contents);
```

Comment: Проблема решена, пришлось немного изголиться над кодом, путем обрезаний и поиска символов в строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите расширение simplexml в модуле PHP.
Если версия PHP > 5.0.4, это расширение должно быть встроено.

**[Установка расширений PHP в ОС Windows](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/install.windows.extensions.php)**

Comment: Версия PHP 5.3.13

Comment: @ЛеМарк, на какой ОС выполняется код?

Comment: полагаю тут [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/1.3.42 (Unix) PHP/5.3.13

Comment: при этом на [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.3.13 - все работает

Comment: PHP обычно компилируется с/без расширения SimpleXML. Я не уверен, но, возможно, он может быть отключен в конфиге. Если есть хостер - пинайте хостера.

Comment: а возможно ли заменить функцию на какую-нибудь другую? может существует какой-нибудь аналог, который позволит обойти эту ошибку?

Comment: simplexml_load_string, но думаю, что эффект будет тем же. XMLReader вроде еще был.